# Lighttpd proxy ip address

Tags: lighttpd

can i use a proxy for my `lighttpd` server like change the ip address or port forward on two different computers, i have At&t uverse.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, adding the following to a lighttpd.conf will redirect all requests for php files onto 192.168.0.10 port 80.

```
proxy.server = (
    ".php" => (
        ( 
            "host" => "192.168.0.10",
            "port" => 80
        )
    )
)
```

Hope that helps